# Any PHP Framework with GD Library?

Tags: php, gd

Is there any php framework with gives classes for GD library?

I have a project where I have to superimpose one png with another png

I am familiar with most php frameworks.

Edit: SQL has available classes in PHP but, we have wrappers and perhaps more organized structure to access it, called Models.
I am asking that context.

Help?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean, but there is this: http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: GD please try to expand on your problem. more details help other users help you.

Comment: Edited my question. Y did you down vote?

Comment: you are asking to search for a library. that is generally considered off-topic. However one library that has what you're looking for is wideimage. Please use the internet search engine of your choice in the future to at least compile a comprehensive list of what you're looking for before asking more specific programming questions about that list then here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GD is typically compiled in with PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php).  No framework necessary.

If your copy of PHP doesn't have it, see the installation instructions here:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php